# using multiple setstates inside map , react

Tags: reactjs

I am not sure why getting a warning by using comma separate two setstate calls. ( warning : Unexpected use of comma operator)

it will not run if I remove the comma or change it to ;

here is the code

```
this.state.subcategories.filter(subcategories => subcategories.ID === this.state.SubCatID).map((item, index) => (
      this.setState({ suggestedPrice: item.Price }),
      this.setState({ category: item.Name })
    ));}
```

Comment: Why don't you make that an actual function body, then? And given that you don't actually want the results as an array, `forEach` instead of `map`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map((item, index) => (
  this.setState({ suggestedPrice: item.Price }),
  this.setState({ category: item.Name })
));
```

This syntax after arrow means you are returning those elements inside. If you wanted to call setState, you should replace parentheses () with body braces {}. Then you can use ; instead of ,
You can also replace those two calls with one

```
this.setState({ suggestedPrice: item.Price, category: item.Name })
```

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

```
this.state.subcategories.filter(subcategories => subcategories.ID === this.state.SubCatID).map((item, index) => {
      this.setState({ suggestedPrice: item.Price });
      this.setState({ category: item.Name });
    });}
```

With `{}` bracket instead of `()` (`;` could also be avoided)